# Trying to select an option with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select, selected

I'm trying to select an option clicking on an image and something strange happens, apparently the option is select but when I search the value not match, he gets the default value. If I return to the page and search again the value matches.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".selectAuto").click(function(){
    $('#prodSel option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
    $('#selectAuto').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
  $(".selectVan").click(function(){
    $('#prodSel option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
    $('#selectVan').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
  $(".selectCaminhonete").click(function(){
    $('#prodSel option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
    $('#selectCaminhonete').attr('selected', 'selected');
  });
});
</script> 

<select class="select" id="prodSel">
                    <option value="auto=_C20_C43" id="selectAuto">Automóvel</option>
                    <option value="van=_C20_C44" id="selectVan">Vans</option>
                    <option value="caminhonete=_C20_C45" id="selectCaminhonete">Caminhonetes</option>
</select>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the code that's giving you the wrong value? This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GRQTh/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting by class when binding the click handler, like `$(".selectAuto").click(` but the options in the select don't have a class, only an id.

On the `$('#selectAuto').attr('selected', 'selected');` line, two lines down from binding the click handler, you *are* using the id of the option.

I suspect that the function in the click handler never gets called.

Comment: I assumed the class selectors were for whatever he is clicking on to change the options, he does say images, presumably not included in the HTML snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set the 'rel' of each image as the ID of the option tag,

```
  <span class='a' rel='#selectAuto'>a</span>
    <span class='a' rel='#selectVan'>b</span>
   <span class='a' rel='#selectCaminhonete'>c</span> 


$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.a').click(function()
          {
             rel = $(this).attr('rel');
             value = $(rel).attr('value');

             $('.select').val(value);
              alert( $('.select').val() );
});
});
```